# C# name process

Tags: c#, winforms, process

i need help, how to do when i run on Windows c# application of name "Game.exe", so that in Taskbar name of application "Game.exe" was for example "MegaCity.exe" ?

Thanks

Comment: +1, just because i HATE looking at question being unvoted and with no feedback on them.

Answer (score 7):

If I'm getting your question, I think you should change the assembly name in the project properties:

[image: Assembly Name]

Answer (score 1):

`Project` | `Properties`, select the `Application` tab, and enter the desired EXE name into the "**Assembly Name**" field.